# 'image' has been explicitly marked unavailable here (UIKit.UITableViewCell)

Tags: swift

I currently have a TableView controller with a UIImageView inside of it. When the camera or photoLibrary button is tapped it should show the chosen picture on the UIImageview however i am getting this error *'image' is unavailable in iOS: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift* and this *'image' has been explicitly marked unavailable here (UIKit.UITableViewCell)* This is the code. It has worked for regular view controllers but not this one.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage

class PostTableViewController: UITableViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UITableViewCell!


    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    var imageURL = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK:Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    //MARK:ImageView/CAMERA & PHOTO LIBRARY

    @IBAction func cameraTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        present(imagePicker,animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func photoLibraryTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(imagePicker,animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
     func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                imageView.image = selectedImage //This is where i get the error

            }
            dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
        }


}
```

Comment: It means what it says. You shouldn't use the `image` property of `UITableViewCell` since iOS7 and the API has been marked unavailable for Swift use. You need to create your own cell subclass with an embedded `UIImageView`.

Comment: The problem is that `imageView` is not an image view. It is a table cell. Calling it `imageView` doesn’t change reality. What you are doing is a completely wrong way to populate a table view.

Comment: Though your variable naming makes it look silly, try `imageView.imageView.image = selectedImage`.

Comment: @Warren Burton How would I go about creating a cell subclass with an embedded `UIImageView` . I appreciate everyones help.(I am fairly new to swift)